# Поиск по таблице Google Script

Tags: javascript, google-spreadsheet

Доброго времени суток.

Не могу найти похожих тем, понимаю что вопрос очень для многих может быть простой, но я совсем попал в тупик.

Дело в том что у меня есть таблица (Google), в которой на одном листе мне нужно найти все значения по тексту "al" и вставить ссылку на ячейки, (где попадается это значение), во второй лист.

```js
function selectText(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("проверка")

  var text = "al"
  var arrData = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  for(var row = 0; row < arrData.length; row++){
    for(var col = 0; col < arrData[0].length; col++){
      if(arrData[row][col] == text){
        var s2 = ss.getSheetByName("проверка").getRange(1, 1, sheet2.getLastRow(), sheet2.getLastColumn())
        s2.setValue(arrData)
        return
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Чуть выше моя попытка реализовать то, что я описал.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне не очень понравилось ваше задание, т.к. оно не до конца отражает суть процесса.

В общей сложности, вам необходимо перебрать значения диапазона и составить массив формул со ссылками на ячейки. Это довольно просто. Примерно так

```
range.getValues().forEach(
  function(row, r) {
    row.forEach(function(col, c) {
      if (patt.test(col)) {
        var nota = Utilities.formatString('%s%s', c.to26(), r + 1);
        res.push([
          Utilities.formatString(
            '=HYPERLINK("%s%s";"%s%s")',
            prefix,
            nota,
            prefixName,
            nota
          ),
          col,
        ]);
      }
    });
  }
);
```

Пришлось сделать красоту, чтобы формулы были как-то обозначены смыслом

```
Utilities.formatString(
  '=HYPERLINK("%s%s";"%s%s")',
  prefix,
  nota,
  prefixName,
  nota
)
```

- Полностью рабочий пример в [сниппетах](https://github.com/contributorpw/google-apps-script-snippets/blob/master/snippets/spreadsheet-simple_search_engine/simple_search_engine.js)
- [Видео](https://www.facebook.com/oshliaer/videos/2695306130555959/)